# Properties of dense sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ be a countable set dense in $[0,1]$ and we have $f(n)=0$ for all $n$ in $A$.

Does this imply that $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere in $[0,1]$?

Comment: No. Let $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is also continuous, then $f$ has to vanish everywhere, since, for every $x\in [0,1]$, there exists a $x_n\to x$, with $\{x_n\}\subset A$, and $$0=f(x_n)\to f(x).$$

Comment: If I rewrite the question with the norm, $//f(n)//=0$ for all $n$ in $A$. Using the continuity of the norm , is this implies that, $//f(x)//=0$ everywhere in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes. It works also with norms.

Comment: How to show this using only the continuity of the norm and not the continuity of f (for example f is weakly continuous or lower semi continuous function)?